# IcePDF viewer customization help

Tags: java, swing, icepdf

I am trying to integrate [ICEpdf](http://www.icepdf.org/) viewer into an existing Java Swing application.  The requirements are that I want to eliminate the top and bottom tool bars and the scroll bar, which I have already done.  The problem is that I also don't want it to have that gray area around the pdf document. I want it to show up purely as a white page on the application.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Added link; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  In the SwingController class of ice pdf source, there is a function called setPageFitMode().

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't want it to have that grey area around the pdf document.

I'm unfamiliar with [ICEpdf](http://www.icepdf.org/), but I <strike>don't</strike> see a gray area around this [example](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/PDF/Viewer+Component+Example). <strike>Perhaps it might offer some guidance.</strike> Is that the problem?

Comment: NB: Download appears to require registration.